# Control the size of graphics

Tags: graphics, size

It could be a very silly question!

Suppose we have the simple case

```
p1 = ListPlot[{{-0.4, -0.24}}, PlotStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.4], PointSize[0.09]}];
p2 = Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.4], Ellipsoid[{0.9, 0.6}, {3, 2}]}];
Show[{p1, p2}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

How can we control the size of the ellipse? I added `ImageSize -> 10` but it does no have any affect...

Any ideas?

Comment: Works fine with me (V10)

Comment: @eldo What do you mean?

Comment: `Show[Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.4], Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, {3, 2}]}], 
 ImageSize -> 10]` gives me a tiny ellipse

Comment: What @eldo means (I think) is that adding the option *does have* the effect stated in the documentation. Maybe there is an effect you're expecting that goes beyond what `ImageSize` does. You'd have to clarify that.

Comment: @eldo Please see my edit.

Comment: @Jens Please see my edit.

Comment: Again, your code works FINE. Restart Mathematica or reboot?

Comment: Why not add the `Ellipse` as an `Epilog` to avoid having to use `Show`?

Comment: @eldo Please post an image showing that the ellipse is very small and does not cover all the area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
scale = 0.1;

p1 = ListPlot[{{-0.4, -0.24}}, PlotStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.4], PointSize[0.09]}];
p2 = Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.4], Ellipsoid[{0.9, 0.6}, {3, 2} scale]}];

Show[{p1, p2}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

You have to scale / rescale the ellipsoid, not the total graphics!

And it might be useful to specify `PlotRange` and `PlotRangePadding`:

```
Grid[{Table[
   Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.4], Ellipsoid[{0.9, 0.6}, {3, 2} scale]},
    PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 2}, {-0.5, 2}},
    PlotRangePadding -> 0.5,
    Axes -> True],
   {scale, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Many thanks!